# Perl change Email Subject

Tags: perl, email, exchange-server, subject

I'm new with Perl and I need to read one email from Exchange and add one ID to the subject with Perl.

I was searching and I had found:

Mail::Internet splits a message into a header object in the Mail::Header class, plus a body. You can get and set individual headers through this object:

```
my $subject = $obj->head->get("Subject");
$obj->head->replace("Subject", "New subject");
```

But I simply can't understand how to make the script to change the subject.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What happens to your Mail::Header object after you do $obj->head->replace(...) ?  i.e. dump out its contents ( with Data::Dumper) before and after you call ->replace.  Do you notice a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

```
my $header = $entity->head;
my $subject = $entity->head->get('subject');
$header->replace('Subject', "Some new subject");
```